# Google Colab上のPython3.7でpipが使えない問題

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Python3.7を使う必要があり、Google Colab上で3.7をインストールしたたのですが、pipがインストールされていませんでした（Pythonのバージョンは `!python3 -V` で確認しています）。

そこで、`!sudo apt install python3-pip` を実行としたところ、"python3-pip is already the newest version (20.0.2-5ubuntu1.8)" と表示され、すでにインストールされているようです。

ところが、`!pip list` とすると "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util'" というメッセージが出ました。

`!sudo apt install python3-distutils` としてdistutilsをインストールしたところ、"python3-distutils is already the newest version (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04)." と表示され、これもインストールされているようです。

ところが、やはり `!pip list` とか `!pip --version` を実行とすると "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util'" というエラーメッセージが出ます。

どのようにしたら解決できるでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

Comment: [5. (3) Google Colaboratory での pip の操作](https://www.kkaneko.jp/tools/man/python.html#pipoptions) とか [2. (4) Ubuntu のシステム Python，Ubuntu での Python のインストール，pip と setuptools の更新](https://www.kkaneko.jp/tools/man/python.html#pythoninstubuntu) のように、試しに`pip`ではなく`pip3`を使ってみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: python3.7-distutils をインストールしてみてはどうでしょうか。`apt install python3.7-distutils`

Comment: `!python3 -V` で正しく起動できているなら, `pip` コマンドでなく `!python3 -m pip list` などと実行してみては？ (https://docs.python.org/ja/3/installing/)

Answer (score 1):

複数のバージョンの Pythonが入ってる場合, pip | pip3 コマンドを利用するとどの Python環境に対して処理を行うかはっきりしません

pipコマンドは, 紐づいた Pythonを起動し pipモジュール内 `.cli.main` によって引数を解釈し実行している模様
なので, 直接 Pythonを起動すると混乱を避けることができます

```bash
python3.7 -m pip install SomePackage
```

参考: (docs.python.org) [Python モジュールのインストール](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/installing/)

---

(追記)

(上記リンクからたどれば) ドキュメントには以下のような項目が記されています
(一度目を通したほうがよいでしょう)

- 基本的な使い方
- どうすればいいの...？ (よくある課題への簡単な回答もしくは回答へのリンク)
- よくあるインストールに関する問題 (pip がインストールされていない, 場合など)

`python` | `python3` など直接 Pythonを指定することで

- 問題なく環境が整っていればモジュール一覧取得など各種機能を利用できる
- どこかに問題があれば何処に問題があるのか(pipが入っていない, その他)がわかる

Comment: ありがとうございます。python3.7であることを明示しないといけないんですね。ですが、3.7にはpipが附属していないようで、No module named pipと言われてしまいました。以下の回答の様に、get-pip.pyをダウンロードすることで解決しました。

Comment: 「python3.7であることを明示」ではなく, Pythonインタープリターを指定する, です(この場合 `python3` でも構わないので)。「バージョンは`!python3 -V` で確認」できていて, (pipは)「すでにインストールされているよう」という前提が間違っていたことになります

Answer (score 0):

以下、Google Colaboratory 上で試してみた結果。

```
!apt install python3.7 python3.7-distutils
!wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
!python3.7 get-pip.py
!pip -V
!pip list

pip 23.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)

Package             Version
------------------- --------------------
dbus-python         1.2.16
pip                 23.1.1
PyGObject           3.36.0
python-apt          2.0.1+ubuntu0.20.4.1
requests-unixsocket 0.2.0
setuptools          67.7.2
wheel               0.40.0
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。get-pip.pyをダウンロードして、python3.7から呼び出すことで解決しました。